# Is there an elegant way to achieve target dependency ordering in Ant?

Tags: ant, build-script

Suppose I have a simple build script with the following 4 targets:

1. `build` - Compile's the project's code, depends on `init`
2. `init` - Sets up the build environment, depends on nothing
3. `clean` - Deletes all files generated by `build` and `init`, depends on nothing
4. `all` - Simply cleans and then builds, depends on `clean` and `build`

   ```
   <project>
       <target name="build" depends="init">
           <echo>Building the project</echo>
       </target>

       <target name="init">
           <echo>Setting up the build environment</echo>
       </target>

       <target name="clean">
           <echo>Deleting all generated files</echo>
       </target>

       <target name="all" depends="build,clean">
           <echo>Full build complete!</echo>
       </target>
   </project>
   ```

The problem here is that the order of `init` and `clean` is ambiguous in Ant. If `clean` is called, it needs to run before all other targets, including `init`. However, `init` cannot have `depends="clean"` because we don't always want to run `clean`.

I realize that reversing the order of `build` and `clean` in the `all` target's dependencies (i.e. `depends="clean,build"`) would technically get them to run in that order, however I don't consider this to be a satisfactory solution. Ant will still consider these targets to be siblings on the dependency tree, and will not actually enforce this order at all.

Another "solution" of course is to just hard code the ordering by using sequential `<antcall/>` tasks. This might be what I have to eventually fall back on, but it's something I'm trying to avoid (for multiple reasons that probably aren't worth expanding on).

Also, I'm aware that Gradle has exactly this feature built in (believe me, I'm jealous of it), but at this point my company's project is deeply entrenched in Ant, so switching really isn't an option.

EDIT - To give a better idea of the sort of thing I'm looking for, here's an example using features that I wish Ant had:

```
<condition property="init.depends.list" value="clean" else="">
    <contains string="${ant.project.call-graph}" substring="clean" />
</condition>

<target name="clean" />

<target name="init" depends="${init.depends.list}" />
```

After reading the manual page on Ant's bindtargets task, I'm starting to think Ant's target dependency list is immutable as part of its core design philosophy, so there might actually be no good answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that `init` never runs before `clean`. Then you can use a property to serve as a flag:

```
<target name="init">
    <property name="init-called" value="true"/>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <fail if="init-called" message="init ran before clean"/>
</target>
```

If `init` runs before `clean`, the `init-called` property will be set and the `<fail>` task will fail the build.

Another option is to have `all` depend on two targets: `enable-clean-target` and `init`. `enable-clean-target` would set a property that would be used by the `if` attribute of the `clean` target:

```
<target name="enable-clean-target">
    <property="run-clean" value="true"/>
</target>

<target name="clean" if="run-clean">
    <!-- ... -->
</target>

<target name="init" depends="clean">
    <!-- ... -->
</target>

<target name="all" depends="enable-clean-target, init">
    <!-- ... -->
</target>
```

The `init` target explicitly depends on `clean`, but `clean` will only run if `enable-clean-target` ran earlier in the build.

Comment: This would reliably prevent the targets from running in the incorrect order, but I'm looking for a way tell Ant how to run them in the correct order in the first place. In other words, this assertion may fail as intended, but then what?

Comment: @CAustin I've added another example that makes use of the `if` attribute of `<target>`.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this just adds a small layer of complexity without fixing the underlying logical problem. If I were to switch around the dependencies listed for `all`, `init` would be called first, which would depend on `clean`, which would fail to run because `run-clean` hasn't been set yet. I'm looking for a solution that is completely agnostic to the order in which targets are listed in the `depends` attribute.

Comment: From the [Ant FAQ](https://ant.apache.org/faq.html#stop-dependency): "The list of dependencies is generated by Ant before any of the targets are run." So, no, there's no way to dynamically alter the dependency graph of an Ant build during a build.

Answer (score 0):

From the Ant Targets [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html):

> Ant tries to execute the targets in the depends attribute in the order
> they appear (from left to right). Keep in mind that it is possible
> that a target can get executed earlier when an earlier target depends
> on it.

So unless your init and clean targets become more complex with additional dependencies, you can count on the ordering to be in order. So `depends="clean,build"` would work reliably.